# get_browser() results empty/unknown result

Tags: php

I try to get browser information that includes platform,browser,version,... in php. But it gives result only for IE,Firefox. It won't give the result for other browser. Tell me the reason.

Comment: You may want to update your [browsecap.ini](http://browsers.garykeith.com/stream.asp?PHP_BrowsCapINI)

Comment: a humbling advice, if you are looking for a specific browser, like <ie7, you may regex $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] this way is faster than get_browser() & more compatible for different server configurations...

Comment: I would like to point out that server-side browser detection is considered poor practice. It is unreliable (some users spoof their UA string; some proxies and privacy products remove it entirely), and is almost always unnecessary -- please tell us why you want to detect the browser? If it's so you can change the page code for different browsers, there's almost certainly some better solution to your problem that doesn't involve the server trying to work out what browser the user has.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have an up-to-date browscap configuration file -- see [Browser Capabilities Project](http://browsers.garykeith.com/downloads.asp).

And make sure the new `browscap.ini` file that you've downloaded is referenced in your `php.ini` file, by the [**`browscap`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/misc.configuration.php#ini.browscap) directive.

For example, here's what I have just put in my `php.ini` file, to test an up-to-date file :

```
[browscap]
; http://php.net/browscap
browscap = /home/squale/temp/1/php_browscap.ini
```